why is there a white frame around my img button

It seem there is a white frame around the img button, I don't know why. I try to do something with the png did not work.
How to get rid of the white frame?
my code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>pokemon cards </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
<body class="back">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>pokemon cards</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <button>BLABLA</button>
    </br>
        <button>BLABLABLA</button>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <button >
            <img src="images/white-hamburger-menu-icon-27.png" alt="menu button">
        </button>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

.title{
    display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: #333;
     color: aliceblue;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
 }

.back{
    background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}

.menu{ 
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 30px;
    display: block;
    border-width: 0px
     }

.menu img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #333;
    display: block;
}

I just started to learn code. I hope anyone can teach me. It says my posts is mostly code so I'm gonna add some details.
First I thought is beacause the image is jpeg so I change it to png but it did not work either.

Hi ! Please use your browser developer tools. Inspect the element and it will show you the styles for it. The CSS for img likely just needs border: 0; if I had to guess.

This is because button elements are styled by default with a border.
You just need to remove it:
.menu button {
  border: none;
}


sorry it does make the white frame smaller but the white frame is still there idk why

You can just check in your browser developer tools.
